# Failed integrity metadata check for Blazor application (NET7)

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a project in NET7 and Blazor hosted in an ASP.NET Core web application. The website is hosted on a service provider. When I deploy the application on the server in a hosting provider, I check the application with different browsers.

The application is working for Microsoft Edge on Windows and Mac. On Safari I get a lot of errors related to the integrity check for all the `dll` in the project.

> Failed integrity metadata check. https://languageinuse.com/_framework/System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll. Failed integrity metadata check. Content length: 1233, Expected content length: 1233, Expected metadata:

[image]

I tried to clean the `bin` and `obj` folders before deploying it from my laptop to the server the application and cleaned the solution but with the same result.

Also, I tried to remove the

```
app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
```

but not luck. I read this could be before firewalls and antivirus could block the `.dll` files and in NET8 something will change for it. But for now, I still get the errors.

### Update

This error is present also in Chrome, so it is not only Safari. I checked the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-7.0&preserve-view=true) but there is not much that I can try.

### Update/2

In incognito mode on Safari, I still have the issue with the integrity metadata check.

[image]

if I open the same website not in incognito, there is no issue with the integrity metadata check but all the resources in the components (*css* and *js*) are not loaded with error 403.

[image]

Comment: .net 8 compiles the `.dll` to `.wasm` now i believe.

Comment: I like to use `.net8` but the service provider doesn't have the machines with this framework yet.