# NET7 Blazor: browsers failed to load resources from the components

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have my Blazor application deployed on a server. The Blazor application is hosted by an ASP.NET Core website. Initially, I had issues with the [integrity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77207008/failed-integrity-metadata-check-for-blazor-application-net7) but after a few `bin` and `obj` deletions, maybe it is resolved.

Now, the application is using some custom components. Those contain *css* and *js* and they are needed to render the page. As you can see in the following screenshot, all the *css* and *js* in the custom components are not loading because of a server error 403.

[image]

PS: other *css* are loading because they are not in custom components.

In the ASP.NET Core configuration, I define the `Content Security Policy` including the domain.